# There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Forbidden (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

Not sure what is wrong but I can't access /dashboard page when I login in with my admin credentials. Page displays a Forbidden.

**Roles are predefined in an enum class RoleName**

SecurityConfig - redirect user to /dashboard after login

```
package com.movie.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;

import com.movie.models.RoleName;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService; 
    
    @Bean(name = "passwordEncorder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); 
    }
    
    @Override 
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority(RoleName.ADMIN.name())
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                        .formLogin().loginPage("/")
                        .usernameParameter("uname")
                        .passwordParameter("pwd")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                        .permitAll()
                        
                .and()
                        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                        .csrf().disable();
                
        http.sessionManagement()
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                        .expiredUrl("/login?error=You are already logged in from somewhere");
                
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

}
```

LoginController - Handle login requests

```
package com.movie.controllers;


import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.movie.models.RoleName;
import com.movie.models.User;
import com.movie.services.CustomerService;
import com.movie.services.MovieService;
import com.movie.services.ShowsService;
import com.movie.services.TheatreService;
import com.movie.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired HttpSession session;
    @Autowired UserService uservice;
    @Autowired MovieService mservice;
    @Autowired CustomerService cservice;
    @Autowired TheatreService tservice;
    @Autowired ShowsService sservice;

    @Autowired ServletContext ctx;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginpage() {
        return "login";
    }

    
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String validate(String uname,String pwd) {
        User user=uservice.validate(uname, pwd);
        if(user!=null) {
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            switch(user.getRoleName()) {
                case ADMIN:
                    return "redirect:/dashboard";
                case CINEMA_MANAGER:
                    return "redirect:/cinema-dashboard";
                case CUSTOMER:
                    return "redirect:/";
                case CINEMA_OWNER:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    } 
    
}
```

AdminController - to display /dashboard contents

```
package com.movie.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.movie.services.BookingService;
import com.movie.services.CustomerService;
import com.movie.services.MovieService;
import com.movie.services.ShowsService;
import com.movie.services.TheatreService;
import com.movie.services.UserService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired HttpSession session;
    @Autowired UserService uservice;
    @Autowired MovieService mservice;
    @Autowired TheatreService tservice;
    @Autowired ShowsService sservice;
    @Autowired BookingService bservice;
    @Autowired CustomerService cservice;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String dashboard(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", uservice.allUsers().size());
        model.addAttribute("movies", mservice.allMovies().size());
        model.addAttribute("theatres", tservice.allTheatres().size());
        model.addAttribute("bookings", bservice.allBookings().size());
        model.addAttribute("customers", cservice.allCustomers().size());
        
        return "dashboard";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String userslist(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", uservice.allUsers());
        return "users";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/movies")
    public String movielist(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", mservice.allMovies());
        return "movies";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/atrailer/{id}")
    public String movietrailer(@PathVariable("id")int mid, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("movie", mservice.findMovieDetails(mid));
        return "atrailer";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/bookings")
    public String bookingslist(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", bservice.allBookings());
        return "bookings";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/madetails/{mid}")
    public String moviedetails(@PathVariable("mid") int mid,Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("movie", mservice.findMovieDetails(mid));
        return "madetails";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public String customerslist(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", cservice.allCustomers());
        return "customers";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/changepwd")
    public String changepassword() {
        return "changepwd";
    }
}
```